# Can we solve Hamiltonian Path problem for biconnected planar graphs in linear time?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, hamiltonian-paths

Assume that we have a bi-connected planar graph $G$ with $\Delta(G)>3$, and we want to find a Hamiltonian Path in $G$. As we know the [*st-order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_orientation) of a bi-connected planar graph can be computed in linear time (By [this Reference](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397576900864)). The *st-order* of a bi-connected planar graph makes a path that covers all vertices of $G$. So can we say Hamiltonian Path can be solved in linear time in bi-connected planar graphs with $\Delta(G)>3$ $?$

**Note:** I said $\Delta(G)>3$, because we know the following rule ([Wikipedia Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem#Complexity)):

> Hamiltonian Path problem remain NP-complete even for undirected planar graphs of maximum degree three.

**Complementary Answer:**

The *st-order* of a 2-connected planar graph with $\Delta(G)>3$ may doesn't give a Hamiltonian Path for it. The following image is a counterexample that shows an *st-order* which isn't a Hamiltonian Path.

[image: st-order]

But there is an algorithm for 4-connected planar graphs that can solve Hamiltonian Path problem in linear time ([The hamiltonian cycle problem is linear-time solvable for 4-connected planar graphs](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0196677489900126)).

Comment: In the counterexample above, is not the following path Hamiltonian (edges numbered 1..12 from s to t): 3,1,2,9,12,11,8,7,6,5,4,10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [graph classes](http://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_1183.html) this is NP-complete even on 2-connected ∩ cubic ∩ planar.

The [proof](http://graphclasses.org/classes/refs1600.html#ref_1660) reduces it to NP-hardness of [Hamiltonian cycle](http://graphclasses.org/classes/refs1500.html#ref_1539).

---

**Added** because of the edit.

I believe the graphclasses proof still applies, but haven't checked this.

Here is alternative proof.

HP is NP-hard in $\Delta=3$ planar 2-connected. Let
$G$ be graph in this class. 
We can artificially increase the degree to get $\Delta > 3$.

Take edge $(u,v) \in E(G)$. Delete it and add edges
$(u,uv,v),(a',u),(a',uv),(a',v)$ where $a'$ is new vertex.

This preserves planarity and 2-connectivity and keeps the
property of having Hamiltonian path.

It also increases $\Delta(G')=4 > 3$.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question with a condition that I wasn't considered.

Comment: @OmidEbrahimi I edited, trying to give alternative proof. Believe the graphclasses proof still applies, it doesn't need low degree.

Comment: What is $uv$? How $(u,uv,v)$ is an edge?

Comment: My question is a special case of 2-connected planar graphs that is not cubic and has a lower-bound on it's maximum degree. If we have  a special case, it may not remain NP-Complete. I think graphclasses reference is a general proof that may not remain in this special case. Can you say why the *st-order* result isn't a Hamiltonian Path?

Comment: @OmidEbrahimi My construction gives $\Delta=4$ NP-hard graphs, as $(u,v)$ ranges over $E(G)$. This works for _all_ cubic 2-conn. planar graphs. If you think st gives you HP, show it, this might imply the unlikely P=NP.

Comment: Your proof truly shows that we can increase $\Delta(G)$ by preserving planarity and 2-connectivity and keeps the property of having Hamiltonian path. But why it remains NP-Completeness of Hamiltonian Path problem?

Comment: @OmidEbrahimi If you can solve with $\Delta=4$, then this corresponds to solution in the NP-hard case $\Delta=3$, so you solved NP-hard problem. My proof need to add that all edges must be tried for HP.

Comment: I'd like to remark that the proof given in [graphclasses](http://graphclasses.org/classes/refs1600.html#ref_1660) about Hamiltonian Path does not seem to be correct (just consider the dodecahedron). Nevertheless, by a slight modification, we can show that Hamiltonian Path is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard even for planar cubic bipartite graphs. Note that any connected cubic bipartite graph is $2$-connected.